# unable to use deflate_init() in PHP7

Tags: php, gzip, php-7

PHP7 introduced a new function: `deflate_init`. Here's the documentation on it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.deflate-init.php

I'm trying to use it but am not able to do so. My code:

```
<?php
$data = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';

$context = deflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP);
var_dump($context);
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'wb+', false, $context);
fputs($fp, $data);
rewind($fp);

echo bin2hex(stream_get_contents($fp)) . "\n";
```

Running that gets me the following output:

```
resource(4) of type (zlib.deflate)

Warning: fopen(): supplied resource is not a valid Stream-Context resource in /path/to/file.php on line 6
```

According to the PHP docs false is returned on error when `deflate_init` is called as is and an E_WARNING error should be thrown from that function as well. But neither of those things are happening so it seems like the `deflate_init` call is, at least, working..

Any ideas?

Comment: Well your error seems to be in the `fopen()` and nothing to do with the `deflate_init()`

Comment: `deflate_init` does not return a stream context resource.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why downvote? That question seems pretty good?

Comment: You need one of these: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Comment: @MarcB - `stream_context_create` takes an array of the form `$arr['wrapper']['option']`. What option would I use for `wrapper`? There aren't any compression wrappers mentioned at http://php.net/manual/en/context.php . And how would I use `deflate_init` with it? If compression could be configured via `stream_context_create` I'd have to wonder what the point of the `deflate_init` function even was..

Comment: no idea. but that function returns what the fopen `$context` is suppopsed to be. I've never tried turning a resource handle into a stream context, so no idea.

Comment: deflate_init is used in combination with deflate_add. It has nothing to do with stream contexts.